# display: block is not being respected?

Tags: css

I have a this page:

```
http://77.240.118.188/contacto
```

As you can see, "Delegacion Madrid" is almost inline with the menu. If the menu is inside a `<div>`, why "Delegación Madrid" is not totally below the menu, but occupying a part of the menu?

Comment: Hi, please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997) thanks!

Comment: Post the relevant code please http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: And there are many many other things wrong with your HTML, this has nothing to do with the display:block

Comment: Post a jsfiddle or post your code, need more info please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you've set a `height` property to your header. The height property is resizing your container (which is a block container).

```
body header {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #F5F3DE;
  > height: 150px; < 
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 26px;
    width: 960px;
}
```

Also, please improve your question so that it may help others.